# SUM of COUNTIF on multiple row with Array formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with 'x' representing that the number on the left must be added at a total.
First row have 1 'x' with a value of 3, so the total of the row is 3, the second row don't have a 'x' so the total is 0, and the third row have 2 'x' with a value of 6, so the tot is 12.
After that I sum all total to get the 39.

I wanted to get the final total without the intermediate results. I know we can use array formulas, but I can't find the right formula. I tried `{=SUM(COUNTIF(B2:E14,"x")*A2:A14)}` but it doesn't work.
Have you an idea ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `MMULT()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `G15`

```
=SUM(MMULT(N(B2:E14="x"),{1;1;1;1})*$A$2:$A$14)
```

---

Or,

```
=SUM(MMULT((B2:E14="x")*$A$2:$A$14,{1;1;1;1}))
```

---

Or, you can use `SUMPRODUCT()` or `SUM()` Function as well,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `H15`

```
=SUM(($B$2:$E$14="x")*$A$2:$A$14)
```

---

Answer (score 1):

[image: my ans]

just look at it..

=SUM(IF(B2:E14="x",A2:A14,0))
=SUM(MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(B2:E14)="x"),A2:A14))